# Are there USB keyboards with special modifier keys?

Tags: usb, keyboard

Are there still keyboards with special modifiers like e.g. a Meta key?
If so do they work with current OSs?

Comment: Note, the "meta" key exists on many keyboards, often labeled as the "windows" key, at least when interpreted by puTTY and the X server.

Comment: The "Windows" key is actually Super, but some software may choose to interpret it as Meta instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some foreign-language keyboards have special keys that the OS may be able to remap to arbitrary modifiers, including but not limited to Meta, Hyper, AltGr, and more.